# Connecting RO to Disposal drainline along with Dishwasher Drainline

Tags: pipe, drainage, dishwasher

First timer DIYer here.

I have a very compact piping system underneath kitchen sink. Currently I have Insinkerator Badger 5 system installed which is taking dishwasher drainage in its inlet.

I want to connect RO drainline to the same dishwasher inlet but due to limited space and orientation of the inlet towards the drywall (only about 6.5” space between drywall and inlet), I was not able to install Drainline adapter (Drain Line Adapter (DLA) With 1/4-inch Quick Connect Fitting for a Water Filter and 7/8-inch Fitting for a Dishwasher (ET116-001, D-25QC, DLA-D) [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08YP9VKHZ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_i_BNRD49QCDADQCJEY50HT?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08YP9VKHZ)).

I tried looking in to 3 way barb joints but couldn’t find a good product that fits the space.

here are some pictures of what it looks like - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UjGFYoqnAUQmY0xgowQUpts90qkw6rP7

Appreciate any headway in getting RO drainline connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rotate the Insinkerator to a better position, you could replace that stubby piece of 7/8" hose with a longer piece and route the hose to a location away from the wall where you can mate it with the Y connector and the dishwasher hose. Then connect the RO to the quick connect.

But before doing that, check the RO manual to see if the brine line will work against a slight pressure gradient, such as the pressure from the dishwasher pump. A quick connect check valve might be required in the brine line.

Comment: Thanks @MTA. I thought of running 7/8” hose but it will be a challenge and very tough to remove and plug a new one since the space is very compact behind sink. 

Would you know of any plumbing connectors that can be attached, which allows for 3 way barb connections?

Comment: @Mac0988 Sorry, no. And a barb connector is not the best choice for the 1/4" nylon tubing from the RO. Better to use either quick connect or a compression fitting.